# observables for api request in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-observable

Hi I'm implementing a observable to make a get to my skill api and I have a problem in the moment to map the data requested.
my array in the end of request keep null, I think that my problem is in extractData().

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Skill } from './skill';

@Injectable()
export class CatalogService {
    private api = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getSkill(): Observable<Skill[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.api + "skill")
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

Here is my .ts where I call my service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CatalogService} from './catalog.service';
import {Skill} from './skill';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-catalog',
    templateUrl: './catalog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./catalog.component.css']
})
export class CatalogComponent implements OnInit {
    skills:Skill[];
    errorMessage:string;
    mode = 'Observable';
    constructor(private catalogService: CatalogService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getSkill();
    }
    getSkill() {
        this.catalogService.getSkill()
            .subscribe(
                skills => this.skills =skills,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

This is a get returned by my api skill:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "experience": "null",
        "typeskill": 1,
        "profile": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "experience": "null",
        "typeskill": 1,
        "profile": 3
    }
]
```

I appreciate the help to solve this issue.

Comment: try to simplify things: instead of `.map(this.extractData)` use `.map(res => res.json()).map(res => res.data || {})` and see if it works

Comment: *my array in the end of request keep null* Which array is null at what exact point in your code? What does your json look like?

Comment: If there is no data property in the JSON string returned by your web api, then body.data will alwyss be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve changing the function getSkill() in my service to this:

```
getSkill(): Observable<Response> {
        return this.http.get(this.api + "skill")            
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

And the .ts file  to this :

```
 getSkill() {
    this.catalogService.getSkill()
                     .subscribe(
                       res => this.skills =res.json(),
                       error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

Comment: Like Jota.Toledo said, the error you are having is in this `extractData` function, your response seems to not have a `data` property, just change it to: `private extractData(res: Response) { let body = res.json(); return body || [];}`